# How can I toggle email notification setting on/off?

Tags: notifications, stock-email-app

I use my phone for emergency notification of critical systems 24/7.  So when I sleep, I can't just put my phone on "Silent", I must mute only my eMail notification (which I do need on when I'm not sleeping).  In this way, SMS emergency messages always go through.

But to do this, I have to press: , , , ,  and then a silent ring tone.

Is there not a simple toggle?  I've tried to make use of apps "MyProfile" and "Notification Toggle", but they don't offer toggles into the eMail system settings.

I am using a new Samsung Galaxy Victory Model SPH-L300 with Android V4.1.2.

How do I get to toggle the notification of incoming email?

Comment: Gmail app? Outlook? Samsung stock email app?

Comment: Stock Samsung eMail app, but I'd be happy to change to another if that would help!  My eMail server is MS-365.

Comment: outlook app offers settings to silent notification based on time

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you only want *incoming* email notifications disabled and not other notifications from the app? If I understood you correctly you won't be satisfied with disabling the notifications for the email app or would you?

Answer (score 0):

Toggling "Sync" on/off does what I need - blocks eMail update (*even pushed updates*) yet still allows in my SMS for emergencies to get through.